# When to retain a "delegate"

Tags: objective-c, macos

I know that in Objective-C you should never retain your delegates because it may cause a retain-cycle, however, how do you know the difference between a delegate and a non-delegate object ? Can't it be said that just sending a message to any object is delegating work to that object ?

Answer (score 3):

A [delegate in Objective-C](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18) has a fairly well established definition. They're typically used in classes that are already implemented, but have some options for customization.

For example, the [`UIApplicationDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is used to implement application specific behavior so that you don't have to subclass `UIApplication`. This helps to minimize boilerplate code.

Also, delegate objects are usually kept around using the delegate property. I would argue that any object that isn't the delegate property, isn't a delegate object. The delegate objects are usually used to act **on behalf of** the regular object.

I hope this helps, your question was quite open-ended.

Comment: There are other delegate-like things, which you likewise shouldn't be retaining, like data sources.